# Sending information to listbox from a class to a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to send information to a listbox to a Form from a class. Sounds simple enough. However it just won't show anything after the method has run.

This is my Class and Method 'Testclass' that is being called from form one

```
    public void testclass()
    {
        Form1 m = new Form1();
        int tostng = "36183464";
        m.listBox1.Items.Add(tostng).ToString();
    }
```

in Form1 I have a listbox which has had it's modifiers set to "Public" so not errors pop up. It will run but nothing will be entered into the listbox. This code works when everything is all in Form1.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: You are calling this method from Form1 and want to add some string value to listBox1 on same form? Btw what is `tostng`, which name has `int` variable, and why are you calling `ToString` on `Add` method?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Yeah so calling the method on Form1 which takes you to a method on the class where it can add listitems to the Listbox on Form1. Thanks for pointing out the variable thats been edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a new instance of the form - I presume you are trying to add items in a listbox on an existing form?

If so do this.

Create a function on the form with the listbox like:

```
public void addItemToListBox(string item)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Then, in the class (remember to add the using System.Windows.Forms reference)

```
public void doStuff()
{
     //Change Form1 to whatever your form is called
     foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
     {
          if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Form1))
          {
               Form1 frmTemp = (Form1)frm;
               frmTemp.addItemToListBox("blah");

          }
     }
}
```

Comment: This was very useful - Just read the "(remember to add the using System.Windows.Forms reference)" lol. Thank you

Comment: Maybe add static especially if adding a whole list:     public static void doStuff()